# PHP AJAX redirect . [help]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that works in a modal way for registration / login. The part of the register is working normally. But the login part has a redirect problem ...

I am using this code below for AJAX. I have done a lot of research on everything I read about windows.location, but I do not know how to do it exactly.

AJAX:

```
 function logar(){

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "validalogin.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){

               alert(data);
    }

});
}
```

PHP: I make the checks that I think necessary before and after I try to create a session through a result in the bank / data that the user typed ...

```
if ($result >1) {
    session_name('nacional');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cpf']=$cpf;
    $_SESSION['senha']=$senha;


    header("Location: my_folder/index.php");

}
```

- NOTE: The header tag is not targeting. Do I have to do something the way the server returns an "ok" for ajax and it changes the targeting? If so how to proceed?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: you can't redirect with header when using ajax

Comment: Why use ajax here instead of just posting to the login script, if you're going to immediately redirect anyway?

Comment: If you wanted to do it this way, you could make the javascript redirect with window.location if it passes a certain responseText statement from the PHP.  For instance, in PHP if the result is > 1, echo 1, and in javascript if responseText == 1, redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You should send a JSON response to your JavaScript instead of returning a header. The header redirects behind the scenes. Do something like this in your PHP:

```
return json_encode(['success' => true]);
```

Then, catch it in your success method of AJAX. You also need to tell your AJAX to expect JSON. Put that after your method and url parameters, like so:

```
function logar() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "validalogin.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .success(function(data){
        if (data.success == true) {
            alert(data);
            window.location.href = "folder/index.php";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by a look at this second code that I sent if possible, your help will be of great validity. Thank you

Comment: You're almost there. You're forgetting to close the parenthesis before your "success" call. Look at my edited version of your logar function. I also fixed the json_encode part. It expects an array.

Comment: As incredible as it sounds the "return" was not working, I switched to "echo" and it worked. Thank you anyway. They are people like you who make a difference. Sorry for English too, I'm not native to the language ....

Comment: That makes sense. Return works if you're inside a function. If you're just calling a php file, you need to echo out your results. You might want to look into MVC frameworks, such as Laravel. They make many things really easy, including things like authentication.

Comment: I've heard of it, I usually do all my projects in the hand, line by line haha, I will give a researched in the content. Since it seems to make life easier for me

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet been able to make the form work correctly. I will post below how I get the code.

FORM:
[I had to send via image due to the organization of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpaR2.jpg)

AJAX ( It's on the same page as the form.):

```
 function logar(){

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "validalogin.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        if (data.success == true) {
            alert(data);
            window.location.href = "folder/index.php";
            }
        }

});
}
```

PHP: (I skipped a part of the code above, but it will not affect the operation here)

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM aluno_login WHERE cpf = '$cpf' and senha ='$senha'  ";

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao);
                while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 

                    if ($result <1){
                        unset ($_SESSION['cpf']);
                        unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
                        session_destroy();
                        //echo "Algo deu errado, tente novamente !";
                        //return json_encode('Error' => false);

                    }
                    if ($result >1) {
                        session_name('nacional');
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['cpf']=$cpf;
                        $_SESSION['senha']=$senha;
                        return json_encode('success' => true);





                    }
```

Should this work?